# cucumber attach screenshot to stepresult

Tags: cucumber, report, screenshot

I'm trying to generate report with cucumber-html-reporter. On it's GitHub page I saw a fancy bootstrap report, where a screenshot is attached to the failed step itself.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-html-reporter

I'm working with cucumber-js 2.3.1 and cannot attach a screenshot to the StepResult.

I can attach a screenshot only in the After hook, where the World is available.

```
After(function (scenario) {

    if (scenario.isFailed()) {

        const world = this;
        return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (screenShot) {
            world.attach(screenShot, 'image/png');
        });
    }
});
```

This is working fine, but unfortunately the screenshot is attached to the "After" step, not to the failed one.

I have tried this:

```
    registerHandler('StepResult', function (StepResult) {
    if (StepResult.isFailed()) {
        return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (screenShot) {

            var decodedImage = new Buffer(screenShot, 'base64');
            StepResult.attachments.push({
                data: decodedImage.toString('base64'),
                mimeType: 'image/png'
            });
        });
    }
});
```

It works, the attachment is added, but not rendered into the report, since the cucumber json_formatter.handleStepResult is executed BEFORE the 'StepResult' hook is invoked.

Can someone show me a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reporter would show the Screenshot link in the failed STEP if you capture screenshot in the STEP itself. If you capture at the AFTER hook, it will show in the hook.

On the example shown in the Github page, it attaches the screenshot to the Step, and so it shows to the "then" step. Please take a look at [here](https://github.com/gkushang/cucumber-html-reporter/blob/develop/test/features/step_definitions/stepDefs.js#L36-L400) for more info.